# Debian extremely slow resume after hibernate

Tags: hard-drive, debian, hibernate, swap

I have a very irritating issue with my Debian 8: resume after hibernate takes from 5 to 10 minutes.

During resume time system shows me picture on a display but not respond, cursor are not moving, keyboard do nothing and I hear working HDD sound all the time.

All console sessions show IRQ kernel message, like this

`kernel:[39559.620706] do_IRQ: 1.225 No irq handler for vector (irq -1)`

Resume process producing over 300 lines to syslog http://pastebin.com/6YZ0kiuc

I have tried TuxOnIce kernel, but got the same issue — resume takes too much time.
Resume issue present on x86 ( old system ) and x86_64 ( updated a couple month ago ) as well.

I have no idea what's wrong, can anyone help me?

**Current system:** Debian testing 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64, KDE 4.14.2

**Hardware** Acer Aspire V5-573G-54208G1Takk, RAM 8Gb, HDD 1Tb

Cpuinfo http://pastebin.com/ZbGQNdXE

Swap partition

`Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda6        201172992  218748927   17575936   8.4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris`

Comment: Are you familiar with "what" hibernate is doing ?  Hibernate is shutdown /suspend to disk if you are still on a mechanical hdd this will take noticeable longer to recover from doesn't matter if you have 1000G of swap its not at play here  for "suspend" it would however.

Comment: @linuxdev2013 sure, I know what hibernate do, but I wonder why resume takes so long NOW. Previous releases and my old desktop never has this issue.
Unfortunately I can't extend my laptop with SSD or change hard drive.

Comment: drive may be  failing

Comment: @linuxdev2013 I have also noticed high I/O rate on root partition (2.5 Gb).
Any way I will check HDD first.

Comment: Same issue here... have you found solutions to speed resume up apart from SSHD?

Answer (score 0):

In recent hibernation implementations, when resuming, only the minimal parts for the kernel to work are written back to memory from the swap; the rest is then loaded by the user-space applications themselves, as soon as it is needed.

While this makes the system behave sluggishly at first, it nevertheless takes less total time to have it operating fluently, as pieces of memory that are not interesting for what you are *currently* doing must not be moved back yet.